# Retrieving GitHub's JSON file

Tags: json, github

Link: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/graphs/contributors

Does GitHub provide JSON file for its Insights page? If yes, what is the format of the URL?

Thanks, I can't find it on the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do provide some (as far as I can tell all?) of the data on that page through the repo statistics API endpoints.

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/